# Coalesce / dynamic WHERE clause with InfluxDB

Tags: influxdb, influxdb-python

I would like to create a [dynamic WHERE clause](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/implementing-a-dynamic-where-clause) in my SELECT statement.

Looking through Google results and the InfluxDB documentation, I cannot find any mention of COALESCE or any equivalent/reasonable way to achieve this purpose.

What would be the preferred way to do this?

Python libraries that will emulate this will suffice for my purpose, but I would greatly prefer a pure "SELECT" example.